# The fastest way to search for all the lines that don't have a matching ID string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I have a large dataset, and I am trying to draw them as lines using GeoJSON. For any line, there needs to be a minimum of 2 points so that it can be drawn correctly. However, I realise that in my dataset, there are some points, that have no matching ID (i.e they cannot form a line as I am grouping them by their IDs which is the last value in each row - wayID). The error I get says `LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples`

This is the dataset sample

```
data = '''lat=1.3240787,long=103.93576,102677,130828
lat=1.3195231,long=103.9343126,106192,190592
lat=1.3194455,long=103.9343254,106191,713620084
lat=1.3202566,long=103.9330146,106190,190591
lat=1.3202224,long=103.9327891,106189,885346352
lat=1.3236842,long=103.9368979,102702,130898
lat=1.3192259,long=103.9338829,106188,464289019
lat=1.3201896,long=103.9326392,106177,473393241
lat=1.3217119,long=103.932483,106176,885346352
lat=1.3217504,long=103.9323308,106173,641080502
lat=1.3226904,long=103.9322832,106172,885346352
lat=1.3226729,long=103.9321595,106171,655522077
lat=1.3231835,long=103.9322084,106170,885346352
lat=1.3219643,long=103.9371845,102882,131521
lat=1.3231554,long=103.9320845,106169,473376614
lat=1.3222227,long=103.9371391,102883,131521
lat=1.3222314,long=103.9349844,106168,190584
lat=1.321424,long=103.9349895,106153,190572
lat=1.3214117,long=103.9351812,106152,190576
lat=1.3215218,long=103.9352676,106151,190576
lat=1.3216347,long=103.9352875,106150,190574
lat=1.3218405,long=103.9351328,106147,190576
lat=1.3218434,long=103.9350341,106146,190573
lat=1.3213905,long=103.9351205,106141,190573'''
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import io
col = ['lat','long','pointID','WAYID']
#load csv as dataframe (replace io.StringIO(data) with the csv filename), use converters to clean up lat and long columns upon loading
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), names=col, sep=',', engine='python', converters={'lat': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1]), 'long': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1])})
#input the data from the text file
#df = pd.read_csv("latlongWayID.txt", names=col, sep=',', engine='python', converters={'lat': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1]), 'long': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1])})
    
    
#load dataframe as geodataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.long, df.lat))
#groupby on name and description, while converting the grouped geometries to a LineString
#gdf = gdf.groupby(['description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda p: LineString(zip(p.x, p.y)) if len(p) > 1 else Point(p.x, p.y))
gdf = gdf.groupby(['WAYID'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())).reset_index()

    
jsonLoad = gdf.to_json()
```

Then save to a file using

```
import json
from geojson import Point, Feature, dump
#save the data to the file 
parsed = json.loads(jsonLoad)
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
#parsed = gdf.to_json()
with open('savedMyfile.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(parsed, f,indent=1)
```

Is there a way to check through the large file and quickly exclude all those that don't have the matching ID? I wouldn't mind converting those not-matching coords into a 'Point' type and those with pairs kept as LineString using the code above.

Could someone advise on how I should go about doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using the column of IDs to calculate the number of frequencies for each ID, and then use the extraction criteria to search for all but two or fewer IDs?

Comment: @r-beginners I'm not super familiar with python yet, how do I go about calculating the freq and getting an extraction criteria? thanks!

Comment: `id_counts = df['WAYID'].value_counts().to_frame()` Now that we can calculate the frequency count of IDs, we can extract IDs whose count is less than or equal to 2 in this data frame and make a list of them. You can delete the IDs other than this list.

Comment: oh it returns me the correct count list, thanks! bear with me, I'm not familiar but do i need to do a `if id_counts > 2:    gdf = gdf.groupby(['WAYID'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())).reset_index()` check ? something like that? not sure how to do the if check for this condition :) thanks! @r-beginners

Comment: Make a list of the returned data and extract all but this ID. `mask = id_counts[id_counts['WAYID'] < 2].index.tolist();df[~df['WAYID'].isin(mask)]`

Answer (score 0):

- this is a simple case of filter in **pandas** before generating **geopandas** GeoDataFrame
- `(df.groupby("WAYID").size() >= 2).loc[lambda s: s].index` will give list of *WAYID* where there are at least 2 associated rows
- then it's a simple case of build up a filter for `df`

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import io

col = ["lat", "long", "pointID", "WAYID"]
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(data),
    names=col,
    sep=",",
    engine="python",
    converters={
        "lat": lambda x: float(x.split("=")[1]),
        "long": lambda x: float(x.split("=")[1]),
    },
)

# filter dataframe so that remaining WAYID have at least 2 co-ordinates
df = df.loc[df["WAYID"].isin((df.groupby("WAYID").size() >= 2).loc[lambda s: s].index)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.long, df.lat))
gdf = gdf.groupby(["WAYID"], as_index=False)["geometry"].apply(
    lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())
)
# check generated geojson...
gdf.__geo_interface__
```

#### output

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'id': '0',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'WAYID': 131521},
   'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': ((103.9371845, 1.3219643), (103.9371391, 1.3222227))},
   'bbox': (103.9371391, 1.3219643, 103.9371845, 1.3222227)},
  {'id': '1',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'WAYID': 190573},
   'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': ((103.9350341, 1.3218434), (103.9351205, 1.3213905))},
   'bbox': (103.9350341, 1.3213905, 103.9351205, 1.3218434)},
  {'id': '2',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'WAYID': 190576},
   'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': ((103.9351812, 1.3214117),
     (103.9352676, 1.3215218),
     (103.9351328, 1.3218405))},
   'bbox': (103.9351328, 1.3214117, 103.9352676, 1.3218405)},
  {'id': '3',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'WAYID': 885346352},
   'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': ((103.9327891, 1.3202224),
     (103.932483, 1.3217119),
     (103.9322832, 1.3226904),
     (103.9322084, 1.3231835))},
   'bbox': (103.9322084, 1.3202224, 103.9327891, 1.3231835)}],
 'bbox': (103.9322084, 1.3202224, 103.9371845, 1.3231835)}
```